# Import package in OSGI fragment which is not specified in host bundle

Tags: module, osgi, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

I have to provide some UI customization of a bundle and for that i am using osgi fragment . Scenario is i want to include another bundle in my fragment module which has no reference in host bundle for example in fragment module i want to include package defined in some other bundle but not in host bundle .

I have tried using `Import-Package`  `Bundle-classpath` but no success

Kindly guide me if it is possible or any other solution to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use Import-Package in a fragment. You will need to provide more details if that is not working for you.

Comment: @BJHargrave thanks for reply ,,i already used Import-package in fragment but it doesn't work.  actually my jar is outside osgi container that is in tomcat lib

Comment: If the jar is not installed in an OSGi container, why do you think OSGi class loading semantics will be in effect?

Comment: let me explain you complete scenario 
I have a jar Foo.jar in tomcat/lib/ext as per tomcat class loading concept this jar is accessible in all webapps .

i am embeded osgi container inside tomcat i want to access this Foo.jar in my bundle name test.jar